# Force Custom Volume on JavaFX MediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx, audio, media, playback

I'm trying to set custom volume when playing a certain media file. However, for some reason, my PC does not respect the volume I set in my program and plays the media file at whatever volume is set on PC. If I increase volume on PC the media file will play at higher volume. If I set volume very low you won't be able to hear the sound (notification).

```
try {
    Media sound = new Media(new File(mediaFile).toURI().toURL().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);

    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.44); //  disregarding the volume I set

    mediaPlayer.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I force a specific playback volume for media files I play through `MediaPlayer` without it being effected by (or effecting) the general volume on PC?

Thanks!

Comment: This [www.programcreek.com](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer&method=setVolume) could probably help you

Comment: The volume of your computer's speakers and the volume of the `MediaPlayer` are two separate things. The latter is how loud the media will play in relation to the former.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks! Is it possible to programmatically change the volume of computer's speakers when playing a specific media file?

Comment: Not via the JavaFX APIs, and possibly not via any Java SE APIs either. There may be libraries out there that provide this functionality but I can't guarantee it. You could try researching a solution, including the possibility of dropping into native code, using terms such as "system volume" or "master volume". Keep in mind that external speakers could also have their own volume which is controlled via physical knobs and such. In other words, you could have the speaker's volume (which could be non-configurable from software), the system's volume, and then finally the `MediaPlayer`'s volume.